# Why is ngStyle background-image not loading?

Tags: angular, ng-style

I'm having trouble getting my image to display. It was displaying before. In my containers/introduction template I have:

```
<div mat-card-image class="quiz-topic-image"
      [ngStyle]="{ 'background': 'url(' + quizData?.imageUrl + ') no-repeat center center',
                   'background-size': '95%' }">
    </div>
```

and in my quiz.ts file I have
imageUrl: 'DIDiagram.png',

and the image is in assets/images/DIDiagram.png

I've tried changing the path to the image, but nothing seems to work. Please can you help. Thank you.

Comment: are u taking any error in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write `background`(`no-repeat` and `center center` are for `background` property) rather than `background-image`

```
 imageUrl: './../assets/images/DIDiagram.png'

<div mat-card-image class="quiz-topic-image"
      [ngStyle]="{ 'background': 'url(&quot;' + quizData?.imageUrl + '&quot;) no-repeat center center',
                   'background-size': '95%' }">
    </div>
```

Comment: yes I've changed it to background, but still not displaying... now i'm getting in Chrome: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Can u check now if image is written in its style with correct name of image from console.log ?

Comment: this is what I get when I inspect the element: <div _ngcontent-oxu-c45="" mat-card-image="" class="mat-card-image quiz-topic-image" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="background: url(&quot;DIDiagram.png&quot;) center center / 95% no-repeat;"></div>

Comment: Can your try edited answer again problem could be &quot;

Comment: U should write also assets path in frond of your url

Comment: I tried imageUrl: '../assets/images/DIDiagram.png', still not working

Comment: You need at least two up ../../assets. First .. is app level, second .. is src level then u can go to assets

Comment: My assets folder (which contains quiz.ts) is on the same level as containers.

Comment: I tried the imageUrl that you specified above but it's still not working.

Comment: Okay, moved my assets into the assets folder in src and all is good now, thanks!!